# how do I achieve this design?

Tags: android

I want to make a design similar to this but I don't know how to achieve that curved imageview. Can anyone suggest to me how to do this?..maybe there is a library or something

[image]

Sorry for not including any code...this is what I've for now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_landing"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView0"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/roundedImage0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/myCardView0"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/roundedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/myCardView1"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/roundedImage2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Make three separate ImageViews and make them to overlap from top or use FrameLayout for each ImageView as parent and adjust views.

Show us what you have tried in Android Studio, we would like to help.

Comment: @Rajasekhar sorry that I didn't include any code before...

Comment: Great! I'll post my solution soon.

Comment: I have added my answer, try this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the final state of view as you have shown above image.
I will walk you through the solution.

[image]

You need a background custom circular background with padding around it and white stroke, so copy this shape in your drawables folder.

**circle_bg.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Now you have to add this background to ImageView.

In your mail layout file i have made few changes.

1. You no need CardViews for any ImageView you can achieve circle crop to those using Glide library, so i have removed all 3 CardViews.
2. Your ImageViews are overlapped and the direction is from top to bottom, to achieve this you have to use attribute "android:translationZ". You will notice this added to ImageView which needs to elevated above other images.
3. Also remove attribute "android:scaleType" because we will use Glide library again.

Now this is your final layout after changes.

**your_layout.xml:**

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_landing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/roundedImage0"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bg"
            android:translationZ="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/roundedImage1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-25dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/roundedImage0"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bg"
            android:translationZ="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/roundedImage2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-25dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/roundedImage1"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bg" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now finally we need to use Glide.
Open your build.gradle file and add below dependencies and sync your project.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

In your activity or fragment class:

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(image1)
            .centerCrop()
            .circleCrop()
            .into(yourFirstImageView)

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(image2)
            .centerCrop()
            .circleCrop()
            .into(yourSecondImageView)

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(image3)
            .centerCrop()
            .circleCrop()
            .into(yourThirdImageView)
```

After making all these changes you will notice this looks exactly same as the image you have shown above.

Let me know if this worked for you.